# How to download a zipped file from internet on to a Windows machine using PowerShell via Ansible?

Tags: powershell, ansible

I have a situation where i want to download an artifact which is a zipped folder from an internet to the windows machine using ansible. I am doing as follows:

```
 win_command: "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://abc/sample.zip" -OutFile "C:/Share/sample.zip "
```

But the above piece is not working at all, so could you please suggest what am I doing wrong? Did I use a wrong syntax of `win_command` or the PowerShell command is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Windows module [`win_get_url`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_get_url_module.html) for downloading files from web.

For example:

```
- name: Ensure the file is downloaded
  win_get_url:
    url: http://abc/sample.zip
    dest: C:\Share\sample.zip
    force: no
```

Comment: could you please tell what this 'force' for?

Comment: It's described in the linked doc page, but if you want to hear it from me, here you are: "*If `yes`, will always download the file. If `no`, will only download the file if it does not exist or the remote file has been modified more recently than the local file.*"

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this:

```
win_command: "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://abc/sample.zip' -OutFile 'C:/Share/sample.zip'"
```

Remember to use correct single quotation and double quotation correctly.